# DB2 - purging and archiving user data

Tags: sql, db2, archive, purge

I need to be able to purge rows, based on user criteria (e.g. older than 3 years) from our DB2 tables.  However, for those rows I am purging - **I need to be able to archive the data such that it can be "deciphered" for audit purposes (not reload/recover the data into its table).**

Of course, the deleted DB2 logs have all the data - but if we had to look at them later (a year or two down the road, say for audit purposes) they would not be a format that we/users could easily decipher.  We wouldn't want to reload since the table and business rules have changed...maybe even the DB2 version has changed.

**So does anybody know if there is a technique or utility to provide a solution for this type of problem?**  Not  looking for anything fancy - maybe there is a "generic" trick for tying the data to it's column name and saving it out to a comma delimited file - or something like that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your purging frequency is low, use a [temp table](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0053719.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F2-10-6-70) to capture the user identity you want to action. Perform an [export](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0008303.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F3-6-2-4-36) joining all your tables (to make in essence a flat table), save your old data to a CSV. Then when the export is done, perform a row delete. Make sure you execute each seperately to ensure data integrity.

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE OLDUSERS
AS (SELECT USERID FROM USERTABLE) DEFINITION ONLY
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

INSERT INTO OLDUSERS
SELECT USERID
FROM USERTABLE
JOIN USERINFOTABLE ON USERTABLE.USERID=USERINFOTABLE.USERID
WHERE USERINFOTABLE.LASTLOGING < '2011-01-01 00:00:00.0';

EXPORT TO filename OF DEL
SELECT USERID, USERNAME, ...
FROM USERTABLE
JOIN USERINFOTABLE ON USERTABLE.USERID=USERINFOTABLE.USERID
WHERE USERID IN (SELECT USERID FROM OLDUSERS);

DELETE FROM USERINFOTABLE WHERE USERID IN 
(SELECT USERID FROM OLDUSERS);

DELETE FROM USERTABLE WHERE USERID IN 
(SELECT USERID FROM OLDUSERS);
```

If youR frequency to do this is more demanding, you may want to create a stored procedure which will take the cut off date and perform the above actions.